# Python Dataclasses: FrozenInstanceError a subclass of AttributeError?

Tags: python, pytest, python-dataclasses

I'm doing some self-learning on the new python dataclasses.

One of the parameters that can be passed to the dataclass decorator is frozen=True, to make the object immutable.

The documentation (and experience) indicates that a:

```
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError
```

exception will be raised.

When unit testing though (with pytest) the following test passes:

```
def test_change_page_url_values_raises_error(self, PAGE_URL):
    page_url = PageURL(PAGE_URL)
    with pytest.raises(AttributeError) as error:
        page_url.value = PAGE_URL
```

where PageURL is a dataclass with the frozen=True parameter.

Any ideas why why pytest indicates that this action (assigning a value to page_url.value) raises an Attribute Error? Does FrozenInstanceError inherit from AttributeError?

Note: If I change the unit test to test for a different exception (ie. TypeError), the test fails as expected.

Comment: Check in shell `issubclass(dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError, AttributeError)`

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b01786c8812c4cc24dd561b5941025bdd6f444c0/Lib/dataclasses.py#L155 Yes it does :)

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. To investigate this I had been trying: assert issubclass(type(error), AttributeError) in the unit test itself. I just realised that pytest is returning a ExceptionInfo class as the error, not the original raised exception... *facepalm* To the shell next time.

Comment: @Steven For future reference, the originally raised exception is stored as the `value` attribute of that `ExceptionInfo` context manager, i.e. `error.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subclass, which you can verify easily with built-in function [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass):

```
>>> issubclass(FrozenInstanceError, AttributeError)
True
```

If you want an *exact* type match in the tests, which I would consider best practice, then you can use an exception instance instead of an exception class. As an added bonus this also allows you to make an assertion on the exception context (i.e. which field has triggered the exception).

```
with pytest.raises(FrozenInstanceError("cannot assign to field 'value'")):
    page_url.value = PAGE_URL
```

This usage of `pytest.raises` requires installing my plugin [`pytest-raisin`](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-raisin).